# R: specifying a string as an argument of a function that calls another function

Tags: function, r, apply, do.call

This is a question regarding coding in R.

The example I provide is didactic. Suppose I have functions called 'func1' and 'func2', where each takes two arguments (let's say scalars).  I want to specify another function 'applyfunction' that has three args: the last number of the function to use ('1' or '2'), and the two arguments for the function.  For example, I want to do something like this (which of course doesn't work):

`applyfunction(1,2,3)` where it would effectively run `func1(2,3)` and

`applyfunction(2,9,43)` where it would effectively run `func2(9,43)`.

Any ideas?

Best, DB

Answer (score 7):

You might want to look at `do.call()`, which calls a function with arguments supplied in a list. It is not to hard to write a wrapper around this that does exactly what you want.

```
function1=function(a,b)a+b
function2=function(a,b,c)a+b+c

do.call("function1",list(1,2))
do.call("function2",list(1,2,3))
```

EDIT: A wrapper would be:

```
applyfunction=function(fun,...)do.call(fun,list(...))

applyfunction("function1",1,2)
applyfunction("function2",1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's another alternative.  You can add more functions to the `switch` list.

```
func1 <- function(a, b) a + b
func2 <- function(a, b) a - b
applyfunction <- function(FUN, arg1, arg2) {
  appFun <- switch(FUN,
      func1,  # FUN == 1
      func2,  # FUN == 2
      stop("function ", FUN, " not defined"))  # default
  appFun(arg1, arg2)
}
applyfunction(1,2,3)
# [1] 5
applyfunction(2,9,43)
# [1] -34
applyfunction(3,9,43)
# Error in applyfunction(3, 9, 43) : function 3 not defined
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really want it done 'by the numbers':

```
> applyfunction=function(n,a,b){get(paste("func",n,sep=""))(a,b)}
> func1=function(a,b){a+b}
> func2=function(a,b){a*b}
> applyfunction(1,4,3)
[1] 7
> applyfunction(2,4,3)
[1] 12
```

Uses get and paste to get the function associated with a name.

Comment: `match.fun` is slightly preferable to `get` for this use.

Comment: @hadley: Why?  Wouldn't `match.fun` just call `get` with `envir` and `mode` args in this case?

Comment: To expand, yes you're right, but the answer didn't do that and the name is more evocative

Comment: @hadley: Thanks, just wanted to make sure I understood.

Answer (score 0):

What about using one of the functions variables as a switch?

```
func1 <- function(x,y,z) { 
## Function One stuff goes here
if (x == 1) { 
var1 <- 1 
} 
## Function Two stuff goes here 
if (x == 2) { 
var1 <- 2 
}
return(var1)
}
```

And, you get to use the same function, with the switch being the variable "x":

```
> func1(1,1,1)
[1] 1
> func1(2,1,1)
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an alternate to switch or paste, just use indexing to select from a list:

```
 function1=function(a,b) a+b
 function2=function(a,b,c) a*b
 applyfunc <- function(n, aa, bb){ c(function1, function2)[[n]](aa,bb) }
 applyfunc(1, 4, 3)
 # [1] 7
 applyfunc(2, 4, 3)
 #[1] 12
 applyfunc(3, 4, 3)
# Error in c(function1, function2)[[n]] : subscript out of bounds
```